# What is the following code doing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have downloaded some samples for Google maps API 3 and I can see some code like bellow:

```
(function (i, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(i, marker);
```

Could some one explain me what this means?  Or can we re-write the above code in different ways? I am bit new to JavaScript and don't know what exactly the above code does?

here  is the full script

function markicons() {

```
    InitializeMap();

    var ltlng = [];

    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(17.22, 78.28));
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(13.5, 79.2));
    ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(15.24, 77.16));

    map.setCenter(ltlng[0]);



    for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: ltlng[i]
        });

        (function (i, marker) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                if (!infowindow) {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                }

                infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });

        })(i, marker);

    }

}
```

Comment: or read this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is assigning the click event handler on given marker so that when clicked, new information window pops up with the text "Message" followed by what looks to be the marker index.

Most likely this code is part of a loop over all the markers.

If I understand your goal correctly, add such function to your code:

```
function AssignMarkerClick(marker, index) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }

        infowindow.setContent("Message" + index);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Then change your loop to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= ltlng.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: ltlng[i]
    });
    AssignMarkerClick(marker, i);
}
```

Comment: could some let me know how to re-write this function ? so that i can pass the i and marker  as a input parameters ? and within the function it will loop through for each markers ?

Comment: Is this function your whole code? It *should* be part of a loop like you say. Anyway please post more code and details.

Comment: Not here, add it into your question.

Comment: ah i added in to the question

Comment: OK, your code place three markers set by you in the code. So what exactly are you asking? How to change the code from using fixed coordinates (e.g. 17.22, 78.28) to using coordinates given by user? Or something else?

Comment: i need to seperate  bellow codes  from the main codes and write it as a separete function                                       (function (i, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(i, marker);

Comment: great it works ! u r a star . thanks for understanding my exact issue and prompt answer.....

Comment: one thing i need to ask you, do you know how to change the window style in to curves , presently it comes like  square window when i click on a specific map point, if we can change the edges in to curve edges it will look nice ..

Comment: Cheers, I fear I'm familiar only with the JavaScript part and not with the Google API part so don't know about those curves.

Comment: that's ok pal. i will google it,

Comment: OK, glad I could help. See you are not new here but you never accepted an answer.. just for your information if answer (not just this one, other answers on your other questions as well) solved your problem you can mark this as accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left. (And by this essentially marking the whole question as resolved/having accepted answer)

Comment: ah thanks for the info mate, i just ticked that V icon..

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (i, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(i, marker);
```

The code:

- Immediately executes the defined function, passing to it `i`, and `marker`
- It then adds a handler to the marker for the `click` event
- When you click the marker, if there is no existing `infowindow`, it creates one

  - It then adds content and opens the `infowindow` on the marker on the map

Comment: is there any looping inside this function ?

Comment: all i need is to seperate  bellow codes and write inside a seperate function                                                       (function (i, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})(i, marker);

Answer (score 0):

Your code snipet is equivalent to the code below except it avoids to declare the variable `myFunc` :

```js
var myFunc = function(i, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        if (!infowindow) {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        }
        infowindow.setContent("Message" + i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
};
myFunc(i, marker);
```

It's a common *javascript* pattern to capture the value of mutable variables (`i` or `marker` could changed if we are in a *for loop* ; without that it would be the last value of `i` and `marker` which would be used in the click handler).